# Using Word/Outlook mail merge with added parameter: delivery time

Tags: excel, email, merge

I have a mailing list. About 500 or so folks. My host, however, informs me that I cannot send out more than 100 emails in an hour or they block it.

So, for the past couple years, I have been dividing my email list up into smaller lists of 80 emails. Then, every hour or so, I run a mail merge on one of those sublists.

As you can imagine, it means I have to babysit my computer every hour.

But then I think "Hey, I know a bit of VBA..." Also, I wonder if I could do this with an additional column in my spreadsheet data (for example DeliveryTime), and a formula just makes that "add one minute" per item. So, assuming that worked, I could do a full mailmerge just past midnight, and it would dump all 500 emails in the outbox, but after that, every minute, it would send out one email. Then, I don't have to babysit, and my host doesn't freak out because what they see is a continuous stream of email, but only 60 per hour. At 500 emails, that's 8 hours and 20 minutes, but I'll sleep through most of it.

So...

How can I do that?

Is there a setting I don't know about? Would I have to figure out some sort of VBA way of doing it?

Thank you kindly,

Edward

Comment: Moderators at strike https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811/moderation-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-an - so I also will not do **any** (further) content/curation-related action here